# processElement emits record even though the state is present for the key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a state which holds a data for 2 mins, sometime processElement still emits the record out even though there is a state present for that key.

```
  @Override
    public void processElement(EngagerEvents value, KeyedProcessFunction<String, EngagerEvents, String>.Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        if (anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value() == null) {
            System.out.println("time stamp emitting: " +jsonNode.get("server_timestamp"));
            // key is not available in the state
            anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.update(true);
            System.out.println("TIMER START TIME: " +ctx.timestamp());
            out.collect(value.getEventString());
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(ctx.timestamp() + (stateTtl * 1000));
        }
    }

TIMER TRIGGER
-------------

  public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<String> out)
            throws Exception {
        // triggers after ttl has passed
        System.out.println("Call back triggered : time : " +timestamp + " value : " +anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value());
        if (anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.value()) {
            anonymousIdHasBeenSeen.clear();
        }
    }
```

My simulator code which produces data to kafka - im pumping anonymousId 111, 5 times

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1; // Number of threads
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ExecutorThread());
            thread.start();
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", key ,""{"anonymousId": "111", "device": "ios"}"");
                try {
                     producer.send(record);
                     Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (SerializationException | InterruptedException e) {
                    // may need to do something with it
                }
            }
```

I'm keying by anonymousId. In my case there is only one anonymousId 111. call back trigger is 60 secs

```
  DataStream<String> keyedStream = mappedEngagerEventsDataStream.keyBy(EngagerEvents::getAnonymousId)
                .process(new KeyedProcessingWithCallBack(Long.parseLong(60))
                .uid("engager-events-keyed-processing");
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? I tried debugging setting a break points, Even if the control doesnt go inside the If condition(sout insid If condition aren't printed) I see that particular event emitted out.

Am I doing something wrong here ? Why is the event emitted even though my out.collect inside If statement ? Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: It would help to see a complete, reproducible example. From what you've shared so far I can't explain the behavior you've reported.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have added more information,  can you please check.  The issue I'm having is processElement collects data even though it is available in state.

Comment: What does the output look like? It's not clear to me how you are able to judge which specific events are being emitted by the Collector, when they all have the same payload.

Comment: Also, you can't expect a job that uses processing time timers to behave deterministically.

Comment: I see you've provided more information in another (essentially duplicate) question. Please merge the two questions into one.